# How to read value in cell from database

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I am still fairly new to Ruby and to databases in general, and am trying to better learn how to use the two together. I have browsed through several online tutorials but haven't been able to figure a few things out. I am working with PostgreSQL and am simply trying to read the data in my database and manipulate in some way the data contained in the actual cell. From a tutorial I have the following functions:

```
  def queryUserTable
    @conn.exec( "SELECT * FROM users" ) do |result|
    result.each do |row|  
    yield row if block_given?
  end
 end
end
```

and a simple way to print out the information in the rows would be something like

`p.queryUserTable {|row| printf("%s %s\n", row['first_name'], row['last_name'])}`

(with `p` being the connection).  However all this is doing it printing out each value in the row and column specified as a whole, then continuing to the next row. What I would like to know is how I can grab for instance the value in row 1 under column first name and use it for something else? From what I understand, it looks like the rows are hashes and so I should be able to do something similar to `{|row, value| @my_var = value }`  but I get no results by doing so, so I am not understanding how this all works properly. I am hoping someone can better explain how this works. Hope that makes sense. Thanks!

EDIT:

Does it have anything to do with this line in my function?:

```
result.each do |row| #do I need to add |row,value| here as well?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you're not using an ORM like ActiveRecord?  Although it certainly has some downsides, it may well be helpful for someone who is new to databases and ruby.  If you want a tutorial on active record and rails, I highly recommend Michael Hartl's awesome free tutorial[1].

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but I can correct a couple of misconceptions. First of all, result is not a hash - it is an array of hashes.  That is why doing `result.each { |row, value| ...` doesn't initialize `value`.  Once you have an individual row, you can do `row.each { |col_name, val| ...`

Second, if you want to grab a value from a specific row, you should specify the row in the query.  You must know something about the row you want information about.  For getting the user with `id = 1`, for instance:

```
user = @conn.exec("SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE id = 1").first
unless user.nil?
    # do something with user["first_name"]
```

If you were to use activerecord, you could just do

```
user = User.findById(1)
```

I would not want to set the value in the queryUserTable loop, because it will get set on each loop, and just retain the value of the last time it executes.

[1] https://www.railstutorial.org/book

Comment: To be honest there isn't a sepcific reason, I have been trying to do as much research as I can and this looked like a good start. Still familiarizing myself with all the different possibilities. Thanks.